# Ng2-smart-table : Use drop-downs or date pickers in inline editing

Tags: angular, ng2-smart-table

I was searching for a better table representation for Angular2 and found [ng2-smart-table](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/demo) is good to use. But the problem is it doesn't seems to provide a direct way to use drop downs or date pickers in in-line editing.

Is there any way to make it possible or what alternative components I can have to represent a table view in my Angular2 app.

Comment: It seems that a datepicker feature for ng2-smart-tables will be released soon : https://github.com/akveo/ng2-smart-table/pull/802 - Using a custom view renderer as suggested is the best option right now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found something like this for drop-downs:

```
private settings = {
  columns: {
    name: {
      title: 'Name'
    },
    valid: {
      title: 'Valid',
      type: 'html',
      editor: {
        type: 'list',
        config: {
          list: [
            {value: true, title: 'Valid'},
            {value: false, title: 'Not valid'}
          ],
        },
      }
    }, //... more columns
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry. I just saw this answer. This is great. Wonder where you found it. What about date pickers part?

Comment: For just simple set dropdown while edit data. this will works fine.

Answer (score 6):

For datepicker:

> In settings[.ts]

```
settings={
columns:{
// other columns here

dob: {//date of birth
        title: 'yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm',
        type: 'html',
        editor: {
          type: 'custom',
          component: DoBComponent,
        },
   }
}
```

> In dob.component.html

```
<owl-date-time autoClose [(ngModel)]="datevalue" dataType="string" 
 (click)="updateValue()">
</owl-date-time>
```

> In dob.component.ts

```
datevalue: any;
  updateValue(){
    console.log(this.datevalue);
    this.cell.newValue = this.datevalue;
  }
where your DoBComponent extends DefaultEditor
```

> In your module.ts

```
     declarations:[
//other compnents here
        DoBComponent
     ]
     entryComponents: [
      DoBComponent
    ]
```

hope this helps !!!

Ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-pick-datetime,
     https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/examples/custom-editors-viewers

Answer (score 0):

I had three issues, when I used the soultion of @ampati-hareesh.

1. "No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute". Adding ngDefaultControl to owl-date-time solves it.
2. "Cannot read property 'isInSingleMode' of undefined". Adding "input" tag solved it.
3. Value is not assigned. Changing the event from "clicked" to "afterPickerClosed" solved it.

My final dob.component.html looked like;

```
    <input placeholder=""
                        [(ngModel)]="dateValue"
                        [owlDateTimeTrigger]="dt1" [owlDateTime]="dt1">
    <owl-date-time [pickerType]="'calendar'" autoClose [(ngModel)]="dateValue" 
         ngDefaultControl dataType="string" 
         (afterPickerClosed)="updateValue()" #dt1>
    </owl-date-time>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

```html
public settings = {
    actions: {
      position: 'right',
      //custom: [{ name: 'routeToAPage', title: `<img src="/icon.png">` }]
    },
    columns: {
      ctg_name: {
        title: 'Category',
      },
      ctg_visible: {
        title: 'Visible',
        editor: {
          type: 'list',
          config: {
            selectText: 'Select',
            list: [
              {value: '1', title:'True'},
              {value: '0', title:'False'}
            ],
          },
        }
      }
    },
  };
```