# How to add datepicker in the ng2-smart-datatable in filter and edit mode?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular6, ng2-smart-table

I dont know how and where to import `renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent` and `component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent`

```
startDate: {
      title: 'Start Time',
      type: 'custom',
      renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
      width: '250px',
      filter: false,
      sortDirection: 'desc',
      editor: {
        type: 'custom',
        component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
      }
    },
```

Comment: i dont know how import that the render component

Comment: show some research efforts & the code you tried - https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: startDate: {
      title: 'Start Time',
      type: 'custom',
      renderComponent: SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent,
      width: '250px',
      filter: false,
      sortDirection: 'desc',
      editor: {
        type: 'custom',
        component: SmartTableDatepickerComponent,
      }
    },

Comment: please update it in your question instead of a comment

Comment: i done it in above qustion @TusharWalzade

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ng2-smart-table : Use drop-downs or date pickers in inline editing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41427742/ng2-smart-table-use-drop-downs-or-date-pickers-in-inline-editing)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you that please once check ant design framework at ant.design on google .I am also working on this. so in this you don't need create from scratch .
this framework is very popular in china . and also my company is using this framework. if you will get any problem you can ask again. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can import `SmartTableDatepickerRenderComponent` component in current component file.

I have add one [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53214429/8612835) before this may help you.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know which concept we follow :

```
startDate:{
    title:"Start Date",
    filter: false,
    editor:{        
      type:datepicker
    },
  },
  EndDate:{
    title:"End Date ",
    filter: false,
  }
```

adding a datepicker in input field